# I have set focus to return to input box but it does not seem to focus?

Tags: javascript

I have created a form with an input box, if the entry is invalid it will create an alert box, I want the focus to return to the input box, however, the code I have written doesn't seem to do it. I am sure it is correct.

I have copied the code snippet below:

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="validate()"> 
            Amount   <input name="num" id="principal"><br/>  </form>
```

JS:

```
function validate(){  
  var num = document.myform.num.value;  
  if (isNaN(num) || num == 0 || num < 0 || num == null) {  
    alert("Please enter a valid entry")
    document.getElementsById("principal").focus(); }
  else {  
    return true;  
    }  
  }
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error outputs in your console? "getElementsById" is not valid. It should be "getElementById".

You also should implement something to prevent the default submit behaviour.
Here you can find a adapted and working fiddle:

```js
document.getElementById('submitbutton').addEventListener('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  validate();
});

function validate(){

  var num = document.myform.num.value;  
  if (isNaN(num) || num == 0 || num < 0 || num == null) {  
    alert("Please enter a valid entry")
    document.getElementById("principal").focus(); }
  else {  
    return true;  
    }  
  }
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit="validate()"> 
  Amount   <input name="num" id="principal"><br/>  
  <button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need the focus to occur without the submit button, as it is part of simple interest calculator. I also have this at the top of my JS:

Comment: window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

Comment: With this EventListener you just listen for the DOMContentLoaded event and then you execute any code you want.

The Submit-Button was added in my example to call the validate function. The question you have to ask yourself is when you want to call the validate function in your script.

When you call it in the callback of this event-listener the user will get prompted by the alert after the DOM has loaded - if the value is no number > 0